# How do I install rmagic 2.13.1 and imagemagick on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I've read a lot of posts it seems with issues on getting the rmagick gem installed on OS X but none of the solutions for setting PATH veriables for MagickCore seem to work for me. I keep coming up with the same stack trace when trying to install the gem.

Here is what I get every time and I am at a loss for how to get past it.

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@recruittalk/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@recruittalk/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problems. I need to say though that I'm very new to Ruby, Rails, Homebrew, (and yes Unix file structures)... but...

I suspect that once you solve the PKG_CONFIG_PATH issue, you'll have another one. I'll make a quick suggestion that may or may not work for the first one and then explain what I did for the second.

First, somewhere I found a suggestion to add this to .bashrc: PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig". I did this a couple hours ago and it may have fixed the first problem for me. I don't remember exactly though.

Second, I think that imagemagick version 6.8 has deprecated methods needed for these:

```
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
```

and so an earlier version will still have them. I followed an instruction here (http://wearepandr.com/blog/article/homebrew-and-installing-old-package-versions) for installing an older version of a package. After uninstalling imagemagick, running the suggested command in /usr/local/Library/Formula/, and reinstalling imagemagick, I was able to successfully install the rmagick gem. I picked 6.7.1-1 kind of randomly.

I really think somebody ought to update rmagick to reflect changes to it's dependencies (it's stale by a year or two). But I don't know enough to do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to the mini_magick gem. You get all the capabilities provided by ImageMagick, but much easier installation and a somewhat lower memory footprint.